# How to use pipeline json string variables in yaml pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I am implementing a yaml based azure pipeline (using Bicep as IaC), the IaC has KeyVault which will store a secret in the json format (below),

```
[{\"userName\": \"user1\",\"password\": \"pssdwrd\"},{\"userName\": \"user2\",\"password\": \"pssdwrd\"}]
```

the objective is to,

1. Use the pipeline variable (marked as secret) to store the above json string.
2. Update the json string variable in KeyVault secrets.
3. Reference the keyvault in Azure function.

I am using the below code to deploy the Bicep template, and encountering errors,

```
 - task: AzureCLI@2
   inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnectionName }}
    scriptType: bash
    failOnStandardError: false
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az deployment group create --resource-group $(ResourceGroupName) --name SignClientInfraDeploy --template-file '$(templateFilePath)' --parameters '$(parametersFilePath)' --parameters certificateName='SignClientCert'  signetUserAccounts=$SIGNET_USERACCOUNTS
   env:
    SIGNET_USERACCOUNTS: $(SignetServiceConfiguration_Accounts) #global pipeline variable
```

**Error shown:** (while executing 'az deployment' command.)

> ERROR: Unable to parse parameter: "user1","Password":

I have tried with unescaped json string (i.e., without backslash `\`), escaped with `\'"` format, all have failed with one or other errors.  What is the right way to handle json strings?

Note:  One option is to store the string as base64 and reconvert it in bicep, but i would prefer to have this as plain string.

Thanks.